# ASP.NET Identity 2.0. Lifetime managment of DbContext object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

Acoording to this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/12/per-request-lifetime-management-for-usermanager-class-in-asp-net-identity.aspx (default ASP.NET MVC 5 template implements this approach )   **ApplicationUserManager** object should be created once per request. It means,  that  ***ApplicationUserManager.Create(IdentityFactoryOptions options, IOwinContext context)*** method is called for every request. But this method  has this code:

```
   public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        ...
    }
```

This code means, that **ApplicationDbContext** object is also created per every request. Thats why, I have several questions.

1. Is it normal to create new **ApplicationDbContext** object for every request?
2. If it is not good practice to create **ApplicationDbContext** for every request, how can I avoid doing this?
3. And in fact, can i replace DI containers with Owin and use ***CreatePerOwinContext*** and ***GetOwinContext().Get()*** methods? In fact, OWIN based approach can replace dependency injection for controllers, but I can not find lifetime managment in OWIN
4. If I can not do this, how can I combine OWIN based ASP.NET Identity and DI containers?

**UPDATE**

I have forgotten to mention, that I plan to use MongoDb and mongosharp driver for storing data. Thay say, that I can keep one connection for all application

Comment: read this article http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/ **entirely**. I believe it will answer all of your questions

Comment: Thanks. Very useful. And what shou I do , If I use MongoDb and mongosharp driver?

Comment: That is another subject (which I do not have experience), you should create another thread, using specific tags and title